# Where find xml styles for Notepad++

Tags: colors, styles, notepad++, color-scheme

I want to find style for Notepad++ like Coda style from Mac PC's or other beautiful one.

I found [this](http://wiki.macromates.com/Themes/UserSubmittedThemes) and [this](http://framework.lojcomm.com.br/tmTheme2nppStyler/). There we can convert TextMate style into Notepad++ style.
In that catalog there is a style called Coda, but it is not the same as the original.

I also found [this style](https://gist.github.com/272115).

I'm using consolas, monaco fonts.

Comment: This question is good. i just spend 40 minutes on this in the morning. I found ECLIPSE XML files are very plentiful someone should write a fast parser to convert eclipse xml to notepad xml...   The fact that eclipse has 12000 different themes and that notepad has only 20 available online exposes the poor theme flexibility of notepad and bad theme creation. good proggy though.

Comment: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=all&page=210 see here